# Pass function from HOC to component (React, React native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner regarding Facebooks ReactJS and React-native, so I started coding with help of a tutorial, showing 
[how to share code between Android and iOS](http://blog.differential.com/sharing-code-between-android-and-ios-in-react-native/).

Later in this tutorial a button is implemented, which toggles a state.
Unfortunately this is made with a mixin. I want to do it with an HOC-component.

**Original mixin**

```
export default {
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      pressed: false
    }
  },

  handlePress() {
    this.setState({pressed: !this.state.pressed});
  }
}
```

**Original call of above mixin**

```
{ ...
  render() {
    const buttonStyle = [styles.button];
    if (this.state.pressed) buttonStyle.push(styles.buttonPress);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)} style={buttonStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

reactMixin.onClass(Button, ButtonCommon);
export default Button;
```

**My HOC**

```
export var ButtonComp = (ComposedComponent) => class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {pressed: false};
  }

  handlePress() {
    this.setState({pressed: !this.state.pressed});
  }

  render() {
    return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.pressed} />;
  }
};
```

**My HOC usage**

```
import { ButtonComp } from './button.common';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const buttonStyle = [styles.button];
    if (this.props.data) buttonStyle.push(styles.buttonPress);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)} style={buttonStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

export default ButtonComp(Button); // Enhanced component
```

When I execute above code, I get the following error (when the call of this.handle happens, so in the TouchableOpacity tag):

*undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.handlePress.bind')*

So what am I doing wrong? Are HOC only to pass data, not functions?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HOC cannot do that. Yet, in case you want a function from HOC available in the wrapped component to be called there through `this`, you must pass it through `props`:

```
    export var ButtonComp = (ComposedComponent) => class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {pressed: false};
            this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this);
        }

        handlePress() {
            this.setState({pressed: !this.state.pressed});
        }

        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} handlePress={this.handlePress} data={this.state.pressed} />;
        }
    };

    class Button extends Component {
        render() {
            const buttonStyle = [styles.button];
            if (this.pressed) buttonStyle.push(styles.buttonPress);

            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.handlePress} style={buttonStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.text}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }
    }
```